# Range selector in javascript. Invalid scope?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, graphics, range

I'm trying to achieve a range selector plugin in jquery. You can see the somewhat working version in

> http://jsfiddle.net/franciscop/yHAY9/2/

However it's not properly working. The arrow above has to go (maximum) to the position of the arrow below, and viceversa. Besides, in the console log, when I move only the top arrow it shows `TypeError: boxpos is undefined`. I think I'm defining the scope properly, is it because I'm not or because there are two elements for the same plugin that interfere with each other? Here's the html:

```
<div class = "range">
  <div class = "start">◀</div>
  <div class = "show"></div>
  <div class = "end">◀</div>
</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
// Make the main form to be draggable
(function ($, window) {
  $.fn.range = function(mini, maxi) {
    // The element to be clicked
    var arrow = this;
    // The current position when clicked
    var boxpos;

    // Minimum position that it can achieve
    var mini = $(mini).offset().top;
    var maxi = $(maxi).offset().top + $(maxi).height();

    // The position of the mouse
    var mouse;

    $(arrow).mousedown(function(event){
      arrow.addClass("dragby");
      boxpos = arrow.offset();
      mouse = event;
      // Avoid selecting text
      event.preventDefault();
      });

    $(window).on("mousemove", function(event){
      // Is there anything to be dragged
      if($('.dragby').length)
        {
        $('.dragby').offset({
          top: boxpos.top + event.pageY - mouse.pageY
          });
        if (event.pageY < mini)
          $('.dragby').offset({
            top: mini
            });
        if (event.pageY > maxi)
          $('.dragby').offset({
            top: maxi
            });
        }
      });

    $(window).mouseup(function(event){
      arrow.removeClass("dragby");
      // Avoid any link/anything that could be there
      event.preventDefault();
      });

    return this;
    }
  }(jQuery, window));
// END OF PLUGIN


$(".range .start").range(".range", ".end");
$(".range .end").range(".start", ".range");
```

Note: if possible try to answer **without jquery ui**, I prefer not to add another dependency just because of this.

Comment: You seem to have an error on this line `top: boxpos.top + event.pageY - mouse.pageY` where boxpos is not defined

Comment: Thank you, but I also found that out as explained in `TypeError: boxpos is undefined`, however I'm not sure why it's not defined while it should be. That's what I am asking in this question actually...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error that you received was due to the boxpos being `undefined` in some cases when the `onmousemove` handler was triggered.

Hare are some problems I notice with the plug-in:

1. mini and maxi should be calculated in the `onmousedown` because if you change the positions of the relative objects (drag the arrows) the mini and maxi you use will still have the initial values
2. Try to save in the context function only needed values and not whole objects like `event` if you don't need to do so. It is better that you just save the starting Y coordinate of the mouse and the needed top value of the arrow's offset.
3. You should pay attention to the events you bind to. For instance every time you apply this plug-in you set up listeners for the `mousemove` and `mouseup` events and you don't unbind them.

The mix of points 2 and 3 are the reason you get that `undefined` error ([Here is a version where the errors are not triggered because only the value is saved](http://jsfiddle.net/dragulceo/yHAY9/9/)).

Look at this http://jsfiddle.net/dragulceo/yHAY9/8/ where I changed your code into this (fixing the issues I mentioned above):

```
// DRAGBY jQuery plugin
// Make the main form to be draggable
(function ($, window) {
    $.fn.range = function (miniSel, maxiSel) {
        // The element to be clicked
        var arrow = this;
        // The current position when clicked
        var startTop;
        var thisHeight = $(arrow).height();
        // Minimum position that it can achieve
        var mini;
        var maxi;
        // Cache the size of the maxi height because it seams that it changes if called after changing the top (because css bottom remains 0)
        var maxiHeight = $(maxiSel).height();

        // The position of the mouse when starting to drag
        var mouseY;

        var mouseMoveHandler = function (event) {
            // Should the arrow be dragged
            if (arrow.hasClass('dragby')) {
                var newPos = startTop + event.pageY - mouseY;
                if (newPos < mini) {
                    newPos = mini
                }
                if (newPos > maxi) {
                    newPos = maxi
                }
                // Set the new position
                arrow.offset({
                    top: newPos,
                });
            }
        };

        var mouseUpHandler = function (event) {
            arrow.removeClass("dragby");
            // Avoid any link/anything that could be there
            event.preventDefault();
            $(window).off("mousemove", mouseMoveHandler);
            $(window).off("mouseup", mouseUpHandler);
        };

        $(arrow).mousedown(function (event) {
            arrow.addClass("dragby");
            startTop = arrow.offset().top;
            mini = $(miniSel).offset().top;
            maxi = $(maxiSel).offset().top + maxiHeight - thisHeight;
            mouseY = event.pageY;
            // Avoid selecting text
            event.preventDefault();
            $(window).on("mousemove", mouseMoveHandler);
            $(window).on("mouseup", mouseUpHandler);
        });

        return this;
    }
}(jQuery, window));
// END OF PLUGIN


$(".range .start").range(".range", ".end");
$(".range .end").range(".start", ".range");
```

This is not a complete solution to what you want to obtain just a suggestion.

Comment: While @MattiasBuelens answer was correct, you went a step further in solving my problem thus +1 and accepted. I had noticed point 1 just before reading this, the 2nd one was due to many try/fail and lack of clean up and the 3rd one I didn't even know, thank you for everything. How is it not a complete solution?

Comment: Three things come to my mind: **I did not test it outside of chrome**, the arrows should go to the top and to the end of bar (so the point of the arrow reaches the ends of the bar) and, I don't really like that there is that buggy thing where the height needs to be cached.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your plug-in does not check if the arrow being dragged corresponds to *this plugin instance*. More specifically, the `$('.dragby')` query returns the same elements for *both* instances and thus they both think that they're being dragged. Of course, one of them will fail, as it didn't set the `boxpos` yet.

Thus, you need to adapt the `.dragby` selector to ensure it only checks elements belonging to the current instance. Now, you *now* that you're only applying the `dragby` class to your `arrow` variable. Thus, one solution would be to check if the `arrow` element has the `dragby` class:

```
if (arrow.hasClass('dragby')) {
     arrow.offset({ ... });
     // ...
}
```

There's an even simpler solution though: just keep a boolean variable `dragging` around which indicates whether the arrow is being dragged. `dragging` is set to `true` on `mousedown` and reset on `mouseup`. Then, you can just check `dragging` in the `mousemove` handler.

Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/yHAY9/5/

Comment: That just solves the problem in two different ways, while making me understand the problem. Now I only dynamically set the maxi and mini to be the other arrows. Thank you so much!